# Free memory for struct corrupt heap

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I am trying to implement "my" version of a Safe Array in C and I have a problem of memory leak when I try to free my struct that I created and I can't figure out the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct safe_array safe_array;
struct safe_array
{
    size_t size;
    int * safe_array;
};

void init_array(safe_array* safe_array, size_t size, int initial_value)
{
    safe_array->safe_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        safe_array->safe_array[i] = initial_value;
    }
    safe_array->size = size;
}

void free_array(safe_array* safe_array)
{
    free(safe_array->safe_array);
    free(safe_array);
}

int* access_array_element(safe_array* safe_array, size_t index)
{
    int out_of_range = 0;
    if (index >= safe_array->size)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return &safe_array->safe_array[index];
}

int main()
{

    /*Create a safe_array and print its elements*/
    safe_array my_safe;
    init_array(&my_safe, 5, 2);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < my_safe.size; i++)
    {
        printf("Element %d is %d", i, *access_array_element(&my_safe, i));
    }

    /*Free the safe_array*/
    free_array(&my_safe);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem appears when I try to do `free(safe_array)` but I don't get exactly what's going on. Can't I free it because I never allocated memory to it, if thats the case, how can I completely free that struct ?

The exact message I get is`Debug Assertion Failed` with a link to a `debug_heap.cpp` file.

**I need to precise that I want to be able to free the whole struct not only its content.**

Comment: You have thoroughly confused the code by using the same name twice, starting with `typedef struct safe_array safe_array;`. Take a look at the function `free_array` where every identifier is `safe_array`. How safe to use can that kind of obfuscation be?

Comment: True, my bad, I did not have much creativity on that one... Still, do you have an idea ?

Comment: Uh.. `unsafe_array`? Sorry if this seems cruel, but if you have not figured out how to use memory allocation in C then you will not be successful in writing a safer implementation.

Comment: I changed the naming, you were right. However if the only thing you can give me is go back to studying, you are not of much help... If you understand what I could do in order to be able to completely free the structure, you are welcome.

Comment: I believe answers below have already answered that. You cannot `free` defined variables, only memory that was allocated to pointers.

Comment: Rolled back. Don't change the question if that leaves an answer without context!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `&my_safe` is a pointer to a struct allocated *on the stack* (by declaring it as a local variable) rather than one allocated *on the heap* (by using `malloc`). So you can't call `free` on it.

Since `init_array` requires the client code to have already allocated the struct, `free_array` should likewise require the client code to handle deallocating the struct afterward. Just as `init_array` only allocates memory for the contents of the array, `free_array` should only deallocate memory for the contents of the array:

```
void free_array(safe_array* safe_array)
{
    free(safe_array->safe_array);
}
```

Comment: Both answers are good, however this one is more detailed. Still, make sure to read the comments below the answer from immibis, they are very helpful ! 
Basically, what I ended up doing was `safe_array_struct* my_safe = malloc(sizeof(safe_array_struct));` and then removed the `&` to `my_safe` in the function calls.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. You can `free` things that were allocated with `malloc` (or indirectly, like with `strdup`). You can't `free` things that weren't allocated with `malloc`, and `my_safe` is not a thing that was allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: Then, should I do something like `my_safe = malloc(sizeof(safe_array))` just after creating `my_safe` in order to free it ?

Comment: @YohanObadia: You have a design decision to make. Are `safe_array_struct` values allocatable on the stack or must they always be heap allocated? If they can be allocated on the stack, then you must not attempt to free the `safe_array_struct` in the freeing code; you only free the array data stored in the struct. If the caller does dynamically allocate an `safe_array_struct`, it's then their responsibility to free it. OTOH, if users cannot allocate `safe_array_struct` values, then you need to change the interface to the creation function: `safe_array_struct *init_array(size_t size, int init);`.

Comment: @YohanObadia `my_safe = malloc(sizeof(safe_array))` will not compile because `my_safe` is not a pointer variable.

Comment: @YohanObadia: You could use `safe_array_struct *my_safe_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*my_safe_ptr));`.  If you keep `safe_array_struct my_safe;`, then you cannot use `malloc()` to assign to `my_safe`.

Comment: In the assignement I have, `we need a way to allocate new arrays with some initial value and free them`. I understand it as being able to free the structure. I think I got the point raised above and I am now facing other problems I need to identify.
I did `safe_array_struct* my_safe = malloc(sizeof(safe_array_struct));` Is it correct ?

Comment: Thank you guys, I solved it ! It is still a bit blurry how heap and stack works, I'll read more about it.